# Remove default style of Html element

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, html, webix

By default below style was applying. How to remove ***style*** **overflow-y: scroll**

```
    <div class="webix_view webix_list-x removeScrollbar" role="listbox" view_id="RailimageList1" 
style="border-width: 1px; overflow-y: scroll; margin-left: 0px; margin-top: 0px; width: 1290px; height: 105px;">
<div class="webix_scroll_cont" style="width: auto;">
</div>
</div>
```

Vertical scroll bar was removing, When i remove Overflow-y:scroll in chrome debug mode. But how write a css or code to remove vertical scrollbar.

```
element.style {
    border-width: 1px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    width: 1290px;
    height: 105px;
}
```

But how write a css or style to remove vertical scrollbar?

```
 .removeScrollbar element.style  {
             overflow-y:hidden;
         }
```

Comment: `.removeScrollbar { overflow: visible !important; }`. Set overflow to `visible` or `hidden`. Add !important to overwrite the style-tags

Comment: Thank you @elveti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.removeScrollbar {
  overflow-y: hidden !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [style] attr on your css an !important to ovewrite the style attr

```
.removeScrollbar[sytle]{
     overflow-y:hidden!important;
 }
```